# How to integrate xmpp with Openfire server in iOS app ?

Tags: ios, swift, xmpp, openfire

I want to make an chat app for iOS using xmpp and Openfire server. I have set up the server and currently running well, but I am not getting how to integrate the xmpp using Openfire?
I have also gone through some tutorial but in that tutorials they used a jabbered client. 
Appreciate any help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some thing like what that I need here https://github.com/processone/xmpp-messenger-ios